# Where is the log of executed Visual Studio custom build rules?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Does Visual Studio produce a log of executed custom build steps? If yes, where is that log?

Is there any other way to display all executed custom build rules (with all macros in them expanded) in order to debug them?

Answer (score 0):

It's up to the build tool to provide diagnostic logging, but you can see what Visual Studio is passing to the build tool by viewing the VS build log. Just [Ctrl]-click on the link to the build log at the end of the build output to view it in the IDE.

Comment: Unfortunately, build log didn't show all the xcopy-ing it did, or tried to do. I'm using VS 2008.